# jaotc library fails to run in javac; java says there is no main method

Tags: java, jaotc

I'm try to compile a mini-benchmark to native code for Ubuntu 18.04 running on WSL.  I'm comparing it to functionally identical code written in C# which is being compiled to Dotnet Native, which runs about 10x faster than MSIL code.  I want this to be an apples-to-apples test.  I'm using OpenJDK 12 to do this.  Below is the commands and code being used.

`jaotc -J-XX:+UseParallelGC -J-XX:-UseCompressedOops  --output Java/Chain.so --class-name Java.Chain:Java.Person`

followed by

`java -XX:AOTLibrary=Java/Chain.so Java.Chain`

results in

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Java.Chain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Java.Chain
```

Code:
Chain.java

```java
package Java;

public class Chain
{
    private static int ITER = 10000;
    private Person first = null;
    private static Chain[] chains = new Chain[ITER];
    private static Chain[] target = new Chain[ITER];

    public Chain(int size)
    {
        Person last = null;
        Person current = null;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            current = new Person(i);
            if (first == null) first = current;
            if (last != null)
            {
                last.setNext(current);
                current.setPrev(last);
            }
            last = current;
        }
        first.setPrev(last);
        last.setNext(first);
    }

    public Person kill(int nth)
    {
        Person current = first;
        int shout = 1;
        while(current.getNext() != current)
        {
            shout = current.shout(shout, nth);
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        first = current;
        return current;
    }

    public Person getFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < ITER ; i++)
        {
            Chain chain = new Chain(40);
            chain.kill(3);
            chains[i] = chain;
        }

        // Ensure JIT doesn't optimize out the first loop
        for (int i = 0; i < ITER; ++i)
        {
            target[i] = chains[i];
        }

        long end = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(GetLastChain());

        double elapsedTime = (end - start);
        System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + elapsedTime + " nanoseconds");

        System.out.println("Time per iteration = " + elapsedTime / ITER + " nanoseconds.");
    }

    private static Chain GetLastChain()
    {
        return target[ITER - 1];
    }
}
```

Person.java

```java
package Java;

    public class Person
    {
        int count;
        private Person prev = null;
        private Person next = null;

        public Person(int count)
        {
            this.count = count;
        }

        public int shout(int shout, int deadif)
        {
            if (shout < deadif) return (shout + 1);
            this.getPrev().setNext(this.getNext());
            this.getNext().setPrev(this.getPrev());
            return 1;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return this.count;
        }

        public Person getPrev()
        {
            return prev;
        }

        public void setPrev(Person prev)
        {
            this.prev = prev;
        }

        public Person getNext()
        {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Person next)

        {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
```

I need to know what I'm doing wrong.  Every example I find on the interwebs leads me to this.

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with `jaotc` but googling tells me you first have to compile Chain.java to Chain.class and then Chain.class to Chain.so

```
javac Java/Chain.java Java/Person.java
```

so full script is

```
javac Java/Chain.java Java/Person.java
jaotc -J-XX:+UseParallelGC -J-XX:-UseCompressedOops  --output Java/Chain.so --class-name Java.Chain:Java.Person
java -XX:AOTLibrary=Java/Chain.so Java.Chain
```

Comment: No. it does not. I just tried with java files only and got `Error: java.lang.InternalError: Failed to find class file: Java.Chain
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jdk.aot@11.0.2/jdk.tools.jaotc.Main.run(Main.java:136)
        at jdk.aot@11.0.2/jdk.tools.jaotc.Main.run(Main.java:102)
        at jdk.aot@11.0.2/jdk.tools.jaotc.Main.main(Main.java:81)
` If you execute row I posted in answer and then call `jaotc` then it does not fail and later execution is successful `Java.Chain@5fdef03a
Elapsed time: 2.9167284E7 nanoseconds
Time per iteration = 2916.7284 nanoseconds.
`